# How to rename qrc file?

Tags: visual-studio, qt

There is project based on MDI example. I work with it in Visual Studio 2013.
I want to rename `mdi.qrc` file. But after renaming I get error

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl qInitResources_mdi(void)" (?qInitResources_mdi@@YAHXZ) referenced in function _main

What do I need to do?

Comment: fix the references (the links that link to your qrc file) and clean/reabuild ?

Comment: I did Clean/reabuild. What are the references?

Comment: Each occurrence of the string `mdi.qrc` in your project is a reference. I *guess* that when you rename the file, theses strings aren't updated

Comment: Each time, you change resources, you should run `qmake`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is need to edit Q_INIT_RESOURCE argument.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(mdi);
```